# Empty Data Providers drop-down indatasource configurator in Telerik Report Designer

Tags: telerik, datasource, dataprovider, telerik-reporting

I am trying to make a simple edit in one of my reports using report designer.

I try to configure the data source in order to test it but i cant do it since the dropdown box is empty. SQL Server connectivity tools are installed.

This is not happening to only one machine

Image:
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the machine.config file for one of the .NET framework versions (x64 v4.0 for me).

Along with the normal entries for `<DbProviderFactory>` and after them there is a blank entry like this:

```
<DbProviderFactory/>
```

Just remove it from everywhere you find it.

machine.config files can be found in **c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft .NET ...**